# Sidebar with multi dropdown submenus are not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a vertical sidebar using Bootstrap 3 and Jquery, this sidebar will have multi dropdown submenus. When I click on a submenu (Option 2.4. in this example), I want to display the second dropdown submenus but, as you can see, the principal menu (Option 2) closes. I'll show you an example:

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu > a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.shown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.1.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.2.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.3.</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Option 2.4. <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Option 2.5. <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the click so that the toggled menu doesn't closes. I have made the following changes to js and also added `!important` to `.shown` in CSS:

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('shown');
});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu .shown {
  display: block !important;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.1.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.2.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option 2.3.</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Option 2.4. <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#">Option 2.5. <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2.4.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Option 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Hi, I have one question, if I convert option 3 same as option 2, with submenus, when I click option 2, option 3 closes, and I would like option 3 closes and option 2 display its submenus, how can I modify it?

Comment: if I am getting you right, then you want to replicate option 3 as option 2 with nested submenus, and when you click on option 2 after opening option 3 then option three should close and 2 should open, if this is what you want then its the default behavior of this code, you can check this fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/deepgagan/4sy93nfc/2/  let me know if I am wrong and you want something else, Thanks

Comment: Yes! That's correct, I see it works, what about if I want those two options keep opened? I mean if I click on option 2 and option 3 both keep opened, no close at least I click on each one again.